# What default object class has firstName, lastName, email?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I have installed openLDAP server and jxplorer on Ubuntu.

When viewing the schema for object classes, I can't seem to find any object class for a user that contains the attributes, email, firstName, and lastName.

I have stepped through the classes: account, uidObject, organizationalUnit, person, inetOrgPerson, etc... but don't see it.

When I try to add the attribute to the object class inetOrgPerson, it throws this:

```
schemaOps modification not allowed.
```

It's not a permission issue I don't think, as I'm logged in as the admin in jxplorer and can add new users or OU's.

Comment: Is your question about OpenLDAP? Or Active Directory? If it's OpenLDAP, use inetOrgOrperson, and get used to the fact that the attribute is called 'surname', or 'sn', not 'lastName'.

Comment: It's about OpenLDAP, but I am trying to make a user importer for all the main implementations of LDAP.  When creating an AD connector, what are the major LDAP implementations?  Should I just worry about AD and OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Which Microsoft Active Directory?

Applies To: Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012
...

```
To create a new user account using the Windows interface To open Active Directory Users and Computers, click Start , click Control Panel , double-click Administrative Tools , and then double-click Active Directory Users and Computers . To open Active Directory Users and Computers in Windows Server® 2012, click Start , type dsa.msc . In the console tree, right-click the folder in which you want to add a user account. Where? Active Directory Users and Computers\ domain node \ folder

Point to New , and then click User . For interoperability with other directory services, you can click InetOrgPerson instead. For more information about InetOrgPerson , see Understanding User Accounts.
```

....
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732336.aspx